From hypervolume to 3D solid graph RStudio
I'm looking for an advice about how to do something similar to the following 3D graph using the package Hypervolume and rgl, to display the hypervolume overlap between my data.:

I'm running the following code:
library(hypervolume)

hv1 = hypervolume_svm(specie1, name = "specie1")
summary(hv1)

hv2 = hypervolume_svm(specie2, name = "specie2")
summary(hv2)

hv_set1 <- hypervolume_set(hv1, hv2, check.memory=FALSE)

hypervolume_overlap_statistics(hv_set1) 

plot(hv_set1, main="a. Specie 1 vs Specie 2",show.3d=T, 
     show.axes=T, show.frame=F, show.legend=F, colors = c("green", "red"),
     show.centroid = F)

The scatterplot that I get is wrong
,
I would obtain smooth 3D solids. How can I achieve that?
this is the output of dput(head(specie1)):
> dput(head(specie1))
structure(list(Comp.1 = c(0, 1, 0.782367218362161, 0.0189539143285594, 
0.955187776070299, 0.456054304244467), Comp.2 = c(0.506016598824208, 
0.216422495760754, 0.919462144900217, 0.681372219919292, 0, 0.476979813131793
), Comp.3 = c(0.435356477269505, 0.537011422304908, 0.738929724677427, 
0.289196178254202, 0.621418853480231, 0.603396889027632)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

and dput(head(specie2)):
> dput(head(specie2))
structure(list(Comp.1 = c(0.472340614903222, 0.325927835046529, 
0.245534540132887, 0.272887943374725, 0.384533458010776, 0.439560326282721
), Comp.2 = c(0.719317859710476, 0.225434087659521, 0.476358549235223, 
0.323667678599905, 0.803420829967659, 0.48750667692359), Comp.3 = c(0, 
0.90482339881728, 0.744437223931766, 0.21705479302961, 0.694891050735555, 
0.571969487191824)), row.names = 21:26, class = "data.frame")


Please share output of dput(head(specie1)) and dput(head(specie2)) as an [edit] to your question. Cheers.

Hi, I've just updated the post with the outputs you asked for! thanks

The alphashape3d::ashape3d function may do what you want.  See examples in its help page, or ?rgl::as.mesh3d.ashape3d.

You can get something like that using the alphashape3d package.  For example,
n <- 200
theta <- seq(0, pi, len = n)
x <- cos(theta) + runif(n, max = 0.5)
y <- sin(theta) + runif(n, max = 0.5)
z <- runif(n, max = 0.5)
xyz <- cbind(x, y, z)

library(rgl)
shape <- alphashape3d::ashape3d(xyz, alpha = 0.5)
plot3d(xyz, pch =".")
aspect3d("iso")
m <- as.mesh3d(shape, smooth = TRUE)
plot3d(m, col = "red", alpha = 0.4, add = TRUE)


Created on 2024-05-06 with reprex v2.1.0
Your shapes look more rounded; if you can define them as contours of some function of x, y and z, you could use misc3d::contour3d.
